# unbinding backbone events with unbind

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

If I have an event aggregator on an object,

```
eventAggregator: _.extend({}, Backbone.Events),
```

and for a modal view, I basically have the presenter of the modal view listen for an event of the modal view.

```
this.eventAggregator.on('modal:close', function () {
console.log('do some clean up');
});
```

When the modal view goes away, I call

```
this.unbind();
```

Does that remove all of the events?  Or do I need to do something like

```
this.eventAggregator.off('modal:close');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would do well to start using listenTo and stopListening rather than the old bind/unbind functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`o.unbind()` won't know anything about objects inside `o`, it only knows about things bound to to `o` using `o.on` (AKA `o.bind`). So no, `this.unbind()` won't do anything about things bound to `this.eventAggregator`, you'd have to:

```
this.eventAggregator.unbind();
this.unbind();
```

to clear out both lists.

Answer (score 2):

In the recent Backbone there is `listenTo` (http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) so you can subscribe to events this way:

```
this.listenTo(this.eventAggregator, 'modal:close', function () {
    console.log('do some clean up');
})
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.doSomeStuff);
```

Then if you need to unsubscribe, simply call this:

```
this.stopListening();
```

Or remove your view with `view.remove` (http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove), it will call `view.stopListening` under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use on/off for binding/unbinding of events you can probably do this.

```
//declare some global object to get the scope.
window.eventAggregator = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

now in the backbone view:

```
var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : 'body',
    initialize : function() {

        //pass the context as this object
        eventAggregator.on('modal:close', function(data) {
            console.log('Clean up');
            eventAggregator.off('modal:close', null, this);
        }, this);
    }
});
```

`eventAggregator.off('modal:close', null, this);` it will help you to turn off the event bound to 'this' current view object.